# Provide permission access to document set

Tags: 2013, permissions, item-level-permissions

I have a document set that I have broken permission with the parent document library and added a specific user to have contribute access.

They have access to the files in the document set, but not to the document set link.

In these links TeamWorkspace is a document library,

eg.
this works.
https://siteurl/teams/teamname/TeamWorkspace/pr-test-access-docset/Test-Access1.docx

this doesn't
https://siteurl/teams/teamname/TeamWorkspace/pr-test-access-docset?Web=1

I don't want to provide access to other documents in the TeamWorkspace document library
https://siteurl/teams/teamname/TeamWorkspace/

Can I set this up so I can share a link to the document set that will work for that user and not provide access to other documents in that document library?

NB. This is in SharePoint 2013